# find the count char of a dynamic text box values without onload function in php javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea

I am having a dynamic text box. I need this text box char count but only one without page load function. Any help?

Comment: Not at all clear, show some code...

Comment: When do you want to count the characters in the textbox? When a button is clicked? As the user types into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="count(this);" />

function count(input) {
    console.log(input.value.length);
}
```

If you want something else, please elaborate more about what it is you want, what you already have, errors you might be facing and code.